# Record type in Lua

Tags: lua, record, lua-table

Im pretty new in Lua but I would like to have record type. What is the simpliest way to define record in Lua? I need to have some array of other arrays.

Something like:

```
Record = {}
field = {1,2}
table.insert(record,field)
print(Record.field)
```

and then be able to read the fields, the amount of fields is unknown. I tried several ways but they were pretty complicated or were not working.

Comment: What exactly is a *record* type? Of course you can have arrays of arrays, but what does `{1,2}` in your example mean?

Comment: some values which will be in first column for example, then I could add another column2 with values {5,6} and I imagine it should create something like Record=={{1,2},{5,6}}

Comment: `Record = {{1,2},{5,6}}` works, then you access the elements with `Record[1][1]`, `Record[1][2]`, etc.

Comment: oh God, thank you, I tried always something like Record.field[1] or Record[1].field[1] but haven't try this...

Comment: The Lua language does not have arrays. A table is a set of key-value pairs. The table constructor syntax makes it easier to create a table with a sequence of integer keys, starting with 1. A value can be anything, including a reference to a table. Lua implementations do optimize maintenance of the sequence part of tables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean record type as in Pascal-like languages...  So, this will work:

```
Record = {}
field = {1,2}
Record.field = field

print(Record.field[1])
print(Record.field[2])
```

or even in a single step:

```
Record.field = {1,2}
```

unless these two happen to be far away in actual code.

The problem in what you wrote is that you thought that

```
table.insert(record,field)
```

will insert what's in field with a key of 'field'.  Actually, only the values ({1,2} in this case) are inserted with your code.